# Folder Path for url in css to access sprite img

Tags: html, css

So I have this image that 3`00px by 100px` and its 3 icons in one I want to use it using html and css but I cannot access the folder the image is on my desktop and the path of my file html is `C:\Users\User\Desktop\index1.html`. Here is the html and css any help I am new to this so I am kinda lost.

**HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<head>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" href="primary2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="button">
            <li class="yellow"></li>
            <li class="purple"></li>
            <li class= "red"></li>
        </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

**primary.css file**

```
.button{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.button li { 
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
background-color: #000;
margin-right:10px;
}

.button li.info{
    background : url(../sprite.JPEG) no repeat;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS file and Image file is available in desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The relative path `../` refers to the parent folder, i.e. `C:\Users\User\` when called from `C:\Users\User\Desktop\`

To refer to files in the same directory as your file, you can use the relative path `./`, or in most cases, the preceding slash isn't necessary... just specifying the file name should suffice for files located within the same folder.

`../sprite.JPEG` from `C:\Users\User\Desktop\` refers to `C:\Users\User\sprite.JPEG` whereas `./sprite.JPEG` or `sprite.JPEG` would refer to `C:\Users\User\Desktop\sprite.JPEG`.

Notice also how you've specified the `.css` file in your html `link` tag...

---

My comment obfuscated the code a bit, so I'll put the revision to the CSS here:

```
.button{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.button li {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.button li.yellow {
    background : url(sprite.JPEG) no-repeat;
}
```

the only changes were to the last style definition.

Comment: Its still not working all i see is 3 black boxes not the color thats in the sprite

Comment: the following seemed to work:

    .button{
 list-style: none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .button li {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color: #000;
 margin-right:10px;
    }

    .button li.yellow {
        background : url(sprite.JPEG) no-repeat;
    }

i changed only the `.button li.info` to `.button li.yellow` and the `background: url(../sprite.JPEG) no repeat;` to `background: url(sprite.JPEG) no-repeat;`

And I get the image displayed in the first `li` with no other background, followed by two black boxes. All inlined.

Comment: some reason when i put same thing it give me 3 black boxes

Comment: wait minute know the first image disapeared any idea why

Comment: sometimes when i make several edits to pages i run into problems with cached copies. the first time i checked it, i got the three boxes (no pic), and I removed the `list-style:none` from `.button` and cleared out `.button li` in addition to changing the color names of the class to ones that weren't valid CSS color names. when i got that to work, i replaced `.button li` style, and got it to work, and then the `.buton` style. i also inlined the style so i could quickly change the filename and reload, avoid any cache-ing. I then replaced the style names (hesitantly) with the color names.

Comment: the spacing between `background` and the colon `:` didn't seem to affect things, but i can check a few other browsers to make sure it's not just firefox playing friendly.

Comment: button li.yellow{
 background-image : url(sprite.jpg) ;
}


.butoon li.purple{
 background-image: url(sprite.jpg) ;
}
i figured it out i need to put backgrond-image not background i dont know why also take away no repeat.

Comment: im using internet explorer i appreaciate all ur saying im learning more and more since im total newbie ur a great person.

Comment: I've gotten the intended result on chromium, firefox (& iceweasel) [& firefox for windows], konqueror, opera, arora, and epiphany. i could fire up a VM and test IE and other Windows browsers...

Comment: the `no repeat` should just be hyphenated as `no-repeat`

Comment: something just wrong cause when i add background: url(sprite.JPEG) -50px; the image doest change its all wrong. could it be internet explorer

Comment: ur genius one last question even though i wish i could talk u all time

Comment: .button li.yellow{
 background : url(./sprite.jpg) no-repeat  ;
}


.butoon li.purple{
 background-image : url(./sprite.jpg) no-repeat -75px ;
}

Comment: ran into another problem i cant get second pox to change color. using the same sprite image and

Comment: right on. time for me to eats, but i noticed that -25px was already moving the sprite halfway off the left side, though i only made a 50px wide sprite.